# port 8080 of glassfish cannot be accessed sometimes

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-3

I created few database applications which I deployed to my glassfish server. The problem is after using the programs several times, the port 8080 where you can access the applications does not send any response. When I try port 4848 or admin console, it works. I need to restart glassfish just to make port 8080 and all my applications work again. I checked for database leaks but I couldnt find anything. I also increased the max and min heap size to 1500mb.

Comment: Did you check to make sure you don't have any background [glassfish] processes running that may already be using that port?

Comment: the port is not used by other applications except glassfish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Adjust the garbage collection of jvm